# Is it possible to @inject with guice the ctor and a member at the same time?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

Here is my code:

```
public class RoutingRequestUrlRepository implements IRoutingRequestUrlRepository {

    String fileName;
    RandomAccessFile randomAccessFile;
    int chunkSizeInLines;
    private IFileHandler<String> fileHandler;
    @Inject GlobalSettings globalSettings;


    @Inject
    public RoutingRequestUrlRepository(@Named("requests_file") String fileName,
                                       @Named("request_sample_file") IFileHandler samplesFileHandler) {
.....
```

why does `globalSettings` isn't iniallized?

Is my syntax correct? Can I @Inject ctor and a class member at the same time?

Comment: Guice isn't magic, there's no way to assign to a field until you create and object, and there's no way to create an object without calling the constructor.  So the constructor has to be called first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is not a good idea to inject both directly fields and by constructor. I recommend to always inject by constructor because doing that exposes clearly dependencies.

Anyway, injecting a field like you have done is correct for guice, and you can inject this field into constructor or directly.

You can use also method injection to instantiate your field as follow:

```
@Inject
public void setGlobalSettings(GlobalSettings settings) {
    this.settings = settings; 
}
```

You can also inject Injector class, and call explicitly `injector.injectMembers( this );`

All these possibilities are explained here: https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/Injections

As your syntax seems to be correct, you should verify the binding or the version of guice library used in your project if your are sure that this field is not really instantiated